# High Scores self contained in .xap

Tags: c#, silverlight

Wondering if this is even possible.  I am making a little game for a fun office project and need to have a high score table that is self contained in the actual Silverligth xap.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If you describe your requirements in more detail, we might be able to offer more reasonable alternatives you have not thought of. Modifying the XAP is not really a viable option, as the answers so far have indicated.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not - you can have a table stored as data (i.e. in an XML file), but you cannot  modify the file and update it inside the XAP file (not reasonably - see SLak's answer).

What you can do instead is either use [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/) to store a local copy of your high scores - note that this file is per user per machine, so you cannot share one file amongst multiple users. Your other option is to use a web service (asmx or WCF) which can be hosted on the same website that serves up the XAP file. The webservice can store the high scores however it likes, and all users will be able to access all the scores.

If you are using SL4 and Windows Phone 7 then you could also send push notifications to the phone upon high score updates. (You can possibly do this with the regular desktop SL app as well using WCF duplex messaging, but i don't know enough about that to comment).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it's probably not a good idea.

You'll need a server-side script that takes a score and updates the XAP.
Since the XAP is (presumably) a large file, updating it will take time, leaving you open to race conditions or access issues.
You could lock around the file, leading to long delays if multiple people submit highscores at once.

Since [the XAP is a ZIP file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2008/03/16/silverlight-2-structure-of-the-new-xap-file-silverlight-packaged-application.aspx), you could update it using a ZIP library and use the Mono.Cecil library to modify a hard-coded array in an assembly inside the ZIP.  (Or update an embedded text file)

Comment: i was little interested  in what u said about "update it using a ZIP library".. can u please elaborate on this..

Comment: You can use something like SharpZipLib to modify the contents of a ZIP or XAP file.