# Silverlight application global data

Tags: silverlight, save, global

I am re-making a Console game, that my boss made a considerably long time ago, in Silverlight. It's totally text based. In the Console version, each computer that had it installed had its own map, which was divided into a grid of rooms.

What I want to do is make the map global; when anybody runs the Silverlight version, they will all see the same map. There is no changing that goes on in the map, only new rooms being added to the map.

So, currently I'm storing all the data in `IsolatedStorage`, which is obviously not global. How should I store the data and retrieve it so that everybody playing can see the same map?

If it helps any, the server that it will be hosted on is a linux server, and has MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer to a person who was trying to do something very similar (he wanted high score data, you want map data): [High Scores self contained in .xap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653989/high-scores-self-contained-in-xap/4654021#4654021)

The fact that you are running a linux server complicates things a little - instead of running a WCF or asmx service, you could consider a java based web service, or just make a normal HTTP page that queries the MySQL database and returns data which your Silverlight app can request and consume (this is still a "web service", albeit a very primitive one).

Comment: You can probably use Mono to expose a web service, that should look much like ASMX (if I recall Mono web service support correctly).  You won't get WCF or WCF RIA Services, but it might be better than using PHP or something that has a bigger gap to .NET.  The important point is that the "global" data needs to be on a server somewhere to share it, which this answer correctly points out.  Keep in mind how your app will refresh this data or be notified of changes, and all that - it'll all be async, so may be sorta hard depending on what you really need.